# Trying to solve an inequality with constants but Mathematica hangs

Tags: equation-solving

I want to solve an inequality $ (\frac{C}{x})^{x} \leq K $, where $C$ and $K$ are constants. I use the following command:

```
Solve[(C/x)^x <= K, x]
```

But it's stuck. What can I do?
[image]

Comment: Try Reduce[(c/x)^x == k, x, Reals]. You'll get an answer and maybe see why that equation isn't as simple as you might think.

Comment: `C` and `K` are builtins, don't use them. Use `c` and `k`.

Comment: Try `Solve[(c/x)^x == k, x, Reals, Method -> Reduce]`. Note `Solve` is principally for equations. For inequalities, you can try `Reduce`, although I am unsure what you count as a solution. For instance, `Reduce[(c/x)^x <= k && c > 0 && k > 0 && x > 0, x, Reals]`.

Answer (score 6):

@MichaelE2 shows how to do it in the comments:

```
Assuming[c > 0 && k > 0 && x > 0, 
  Reduce[(c/x)^x <= k && c > 0 && k > 0 && x > 0, x, Reals] // FullSimplify]
```

gives five branches of solutions. Mathematica typically gives these branches in a quite convoluted way and requires a bit of manual simplification to merge them into human-understandable form. Particularly, equality conditions are often (as here) listed separately from inequality conditions, even though they could be merged.

Cleaning up a bit yields a three-fold case distinction on $k$:

- If $k<1$ we have $x\geq c e^{W\left(-\frac{\log (k)}{c}\right)}$,
- if $1\leq k\leq e^{c/e}$ we have two regions of solutions coming from the two branches of the [Lambert W function](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ProductLog.html):
  $x\leq c e^{W_{-1}\left(-\frac{\log (k)}{c}\right)}$ and $x\geq c e^{W\left(-\frac{\log (k)}{c}\right)}$,
- if $k\geq e^{c/e}$ we have $x>0$.

Let's try it out with $c=2$:

```
With[{c = 2},
  Plot[(c/x)^x, {x, 0, 6}, GridLines -> {{c/E}, {1, E^(c/E)}}]]
```

[image]

We see clearly the case distinction on $k$:

- If $k<1$ then $x$ must lie on the right of the tail of the curve,
- if $1\leq k\leq e^{c/e}=2.09\ldots$ (the top of the curve) we have two regions of solutions, a finite one to the left and an infinite one to the right,
- if $k\geq e^{c/e}=2.09\ldots$ any value of $x$ will satisfy the inequality.

### update: a bit more math

The inequality is

$$
\left(\frac{c}{x}\right)^x \leq k
$$
with $c,k,x>0$.

Let's scale $y=x/c$:
$$
y^{-c y} \leq k
$$
and by taking the $(-1/c)$'th power on both sides,
$$
y^y \geq k^{-1/c}
$$
So we can merge the two parameters $c,k$ into a single parameter $a=k^{-1/c}$, and find the values of $y>0$ that satisfy $y^y\geq a$.

```
LogPlot[y^y, {y, 0, 2}]
```

[image]

From this plot it is clear that there are three cases:

- For $a\leq e^{-1/e}$, all values of $y$ satisfy $y^y\geq a$, because $e^{-1/e}=0.692201\ldots$ is the smallest value that the function $y^y$ can take.
- For $e^{-1/e}<a\leq1$ there are two branches of solutions for $y$: we can have $y\leq e^{W_{-1}(\ln a)}$ or $y\geq e^{W_{0}(\ln a)}$.
- For $a>1$ we only have the branch $y\geq e^{W_{0}(\ln a)}$.

Comment: ！your explaination helps me a lot